# Simple moviepy script, getting error: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, moviepy

i'm working on a little script to concat all clips in a folder with a small transition using moviepy, but I'm unable to run it as I'm getting the error unhashable type 'list'. I've been reading through many posts about this error and I understand that you're unable to hash a list, and casting to a tuple can fix the problem, i've tried multiple suggestions from other answers but can't fully understand why my code isn't fully working

```
from moviepy.editor import concatenate_videoclips
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip  
import os


clips = []
    for filename in os.listdir('D:/Clip Project/ClipsTest'):
        if filename.endswith(".mp4"):
            clips.append(VideoFileClip('D:/Clip Project/ClipsTest/' + filename))
    clips = [clip.crossfadein(1) for clip in clips]
    video = concatenate_videoclips(clips, padding=-1, method='compose', )
    video.write_videofile('D:/Clip Project/ClipsTest/League-' + '.mp4', threads=4, fps=24)
```

This is the code I orginally ran into the problem with and am struggling to fix, any tips would be amazing!

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teststuff.py", line 2, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import concatenate_videoclips
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 48, in <module>
    import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\fx\all\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __all__ = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\fx\all\__init__.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    __all__ = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pkgutil.py", line 129, in iter_modules
    for i in importers:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pkgutil.py", line 415, in get_importer
    importer = sys.path_importer_cache[path_item]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is it possible this is an issue with moviepy itself? I've looked into the documentation below but to no avail, as well as fiddled with the imports.

Comment: You should include the full error text in your question so we can see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Sorry, I completely blanked on adding it, thanks for the reminder

Comment: Can you share more of the code - including imports.

Comment: Just added the imports, that's the entire code.

Comment: So it looks like the problem is in the `import`, which means there won't be much you can do about it.  You might try breaking that into two parts: `from moviepy import editor` and `from editor import concatenate_videoclips` just in case there's some initialization being skipped.

Comment: Unfortunetly tried that and it didn't work, so it's possibly a problem with moviepy?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what is causing the error but an example to replicate the error:

```
d ={ 1:'first', [2,3]:'second'}
print(d)
```

I looked a litter in the pymovie documentation but could not find the parameters. Try to check and see the parameters the compose function requires.

You can see here the functions parameters:
https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/compositing/concatenate.py
maybe this can help.